# Irreducible polynomial with roots mod p for all but finitely many p

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

It’s a theorem of Brandl, Bubboloni, and Hupp that polynomials over Q which have roots modulo all primes are either linear or the product of at least two irreducible factors.

Is this still true if you replace “all primes” by “all but finitely many primes”?

Comment: Does not this follow from Chebotarev (or even earlier) density theorem?

Comment: Yes, as suggested by Fedor Petrov: Even the weaker Frobenius density theorem (see https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02839049 or  https://www.isibang.ac.in/~sury/frobreso.pdf) shows that each element of the Galois group has a fixed point. Then by an easy theorem of Jordan, the Galois group is intransitive (or the polynomial is linear). Note that the orbits of the Galois group correspond to the irreducible factors of the polynomial.

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Comment: If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13):

The result in the original post was surely known to Kronecker. Indeed, let $f$ be a polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$, and let $p$ run through the primes. Kronecker (1880) proved that the number of irreducible factors of $f$ equals the average number of zeros of $f\bmod p$, while $f\bmod p$ splits into linear factors for a positive density of primes $p$. See [Lenstra-Stevenhagen: Chebotarev and his density theorem](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Ehwl/PUBLICATIONS/1996d/art.pdf).

In particular, the answer to the OP's question is "yes", and one can even derive the following stronger statement. If $f\bmod p$ has a root for a set of primes $p$ of density exceeding
$$1-\frac{\deg(f)-1}{\deg(f)!},$$
then $f$ has at least two irreducible factors.